# Drawing both statically and dynamically in java

Tags: java, graphics, paint

I made a paint application. And need your help to solve a problem. As you can see this code draws the shapes again and again when paint event is called. When there is many shapes, the preview rectangle feature becomes slow and doesn't work smoothly. Is there any way to draw shapes only when mouse pressing and releasing? When I tried shapes began to disappear while mouse dragging and appears when mouse Released.

Here is Essential code:

```
private class drawer extends JComponent{
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    ArrayList<Color> fillcolo = new ArrayList<Color>();
    ArrayList<Color> strokecolo = new ArrayList<Color>();
    Point drawst, drawend;

    public drawer(){
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                drawst = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                drawend = drawst;

                if(currentaction == 0){
                    ArrayList<Shape> availables = new ArrayList<Shape>();
                    for(Shape s : shapes){
                        if(s.contains(drawst)){
                            availables.add(s);
                        }
                    }
                    if(!availables.isEmpty()){
                        int tmpindex = shapes.indexOf(availables.get(availables.size() -1));
                        shapes.remove(tmpindex);
                        fillcolo.remove(tmpindex);
                        strokecolo.remove(tmpindex);
                    }
                }

                flowthrough = true;
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                switch (currentaction){

                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Shape shape01 = drawellipse(drawst.x,drawst.y,e.getX(),e.getY());
                    shapes.add(shape01);
                    fillcolo.add(fillcol);
                    strokecolo.add(strokecol);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Shape shape = drawrect(drawst.x,drawst.y,e.getX(),e.getY());
                    shapes.add(shape);
                    fillcolo.add(fillcol);
                    strokecolo.add(strokecol);
                    break;
                }

                drawst = null; drawend = null;
                flowthrough = true;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                drawend = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();
            }
        }
        );
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D)g;

        graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graph.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f));

        graph.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

        if(flowthrough){
            Iterator<Color> strokecounter = strokecolo.iterator();
            Iterator<Color> fillcounter =  fillcolo.iterator();

            for(Shape s : shapes){
                graph.setPaint(strokecounter.next());
                graph.draw(s);
                graph.setPaint(fillcounter.next());
                graph.fill(s);
            }
        }
        if(drawst != null && drawend != null){
            switch (currentaction){
            case 4:
                graph.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));
                graph.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                Shape bshape = drawellipse(drawst.x, drawst.y, drawend.x, drawend.y);
                graph.draw(bshape);
                break;
            case 3:
                graph.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));
                graph.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                Shape ashape = drawrect(drawst.x, drawst.y, drawend.x, drawend.y);
                graph.draw(ashape);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private Rectangle2D.Float drawrect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
        int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

        int width = Math.abs(x1-x2);
        int height = Math.abs(y1-y2);

        return new Rectangle2D.Float(x,y,width,height);
    }

    private Ellipse2D.Float drawellipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
        int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

        int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
        int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

        return new Ellipse2D.Float(x,y,width,height);
    }
}
```

Here is full code(I minimized it a bit):

```
public class Basics extends JFrame {
JButton brushbut, shapebut, linebut, strokecolbut, fillcolbut;
int currentaction = 1;
int strokesize = 2;
boolean flowthrough = false;

Color strokecol = Color.black, fillcol = Color.darkGray;

public Basics(){
    this.setBounds(new Rectangle(50,50,1000,600));
    this.setTitle("Dandle");

    JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
    Box thebox = Box.createHorizontalBox();

    brushbut = makebutton("/home/kamal/Pictures/brushicon(sized).png", 4);
    shapebut = makebutton("/home/kamal/Pictures/shapeicon(sized).png", 3);
    linebut = makebutton("/home/kamal/Pictures/vector-path-lineicon(sized).png",0);
    strokecolbut = makebutton("/home/kamal/Pictures/strokecolor(sized).png", true);
    fillcolbut = makebutton("/home/kamal/Pictures/fill-coloricon(sized).png", false);

    thebox.add(brushbut);
    ........

    buttonpanel.add(thebox);
    this.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(new drawer(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private JButton makebutton(String icon, final int num){
    JButton thebut = new JButton();
    ........
    thebut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            currentaction = num;
        }
    });

    return thebut;
}

private JButton makebutton(String icon, final boolean stroke){
    JButton thebut = new JButton();
    thebut.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));
    thebut.setSize(50,50);

    thebut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(stroke) strokecol = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick a stroke", strokecol);
            ..........
        }
    });

    return thebut;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Basics().setVisible(true);
}

private class drawer extends JComponent{
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    ArrayList<Color> fillcolo = new ArrayList<Color>();
    ArrayList<Color> strokecolo = new ArrayList<Color>();
    Point drawst, drawend;

    public drawer(){
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                drawst = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                drawend = drawst;

                if(currentaction == 0){
                    ArrayList<Shape> availables = new ArrayList<Shape>();
                    for(Shape s : shapes){
                        if(s.contains(drawst)){
                            availables.add(s);
                        }
                    }
                    if(!availables.isEmpty()){
                        int tmpindex = shapes.indexOf(availables.get(availables.size() -1));
                        shapes.remove(tmpindex);
                        fillcolo.remove(tmpindex);
                        strokecolo.remove(tmpindex);
                    }
                }

                flowthrough = true;
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                switch (currentaction){

                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Shape shape01 = drawellipse(drawst.x,drawst.y,e.getX(),e.getY());
                    shapes.add(shape01);
                    fillcolo.add(fillcol);
                    strokecolo.add(strokecol);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Shape shape = drawrect(drawst.x,drawst.y,e.getX(),e.getY());
                    shapes.add(shape);
                    fillcolo.add(fillcol);
                    strokecolo.add(strokecol);
                    break;
                }

                drawst = null; drawend = null;
                flowthrough = true;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                drawend = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();
            }
        }
        );
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D)g;

        graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graph.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f));

        graph.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

        if(flowthrough){
            Iterator<Color> strokecounter = strokecolo.iterator();
            Iterator<Color> fillcounter =  fillcolo.iterator();

            for(Shape s : shapes){
                graph.setPaint(strokecounter.next());
                graph.draw(s);
                graph.setPaint(fillcounter.next());
                graph.fill(s);
            }
        }
        if(drawst != null && drawend != null){
            switch (currentaction){
            case 4:
                graph.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));
                graph.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                Shape bshape = drawellipse(drawst.x, drawst.y, drawend.x, drawend.y);
                graph.draw(bshape);
                break;
            case 3:
                graph.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));
                graph.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                Shape ashape = drawrect(drawst.x, drawst.y, drawend.x, drawend.y);
                graph.draw(ashape);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private Rectangle2D.Float drawrect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        ..........
        return new Rectangle2D.Float(x,y,width,height);
    }

    private Ellipse2D.Float drawellipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        ..........
        return new Ellipse2D.Float(x,y,width,height);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of repainting everything, try [repainting only the relevant rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint-int-int-int-int-).  Also, you should override paintComponent, not paint, and call super.paintComponent;  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.